# IntelliJ IDEA Cache Not Refreshing

Tags: caching, intellij-idea, ide

System and IDE specs:
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.4
Build #IC-163.12024.16, built on January 31, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-408-b6 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

The caching for IntelliJ IDEA is not updating/refreshing.
Whenever I make a change to my code and save the file, I must Invalidate Caches and Restart before building and testing my app on my device.
As you can imagine, this is a huge pain.

I have tested to make sure that it is the cache's fault, and it is the cache.
Rebuilding the project has no effect.
It is not my code, my code is working, if I add a simple logging call and try to build and test it, the logging call is never made. But if I Invalidate and Restart and then build, then the logging call is made.

Is there a setting that modifies cache persistence/size?
Is there a setting/method of disabling the cache? (I am aware this will make my compile time and code completion/suggestion long, but at this point I don't care.)
Are there any plugins to manage the caching system?

I feel like a fool for updating to the latest version of IDEA, but I am hopeful for a solution.

**Edit**:
Here is a log file from opening, compiling and running, make a change, compile and run (no change), invalidate and restart, compile and run (change happens): https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2IlQZXFvp4TMjFMM3NfNlRMLTg

Comment: Does it happen with any project, even hello word? If not, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also check idea.log for errors, enable debug logging for [build.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) and check it for possible problems.

Comment: @CrazyCoder A simple HelloWorld App compiles fine even when changed a little. My app has multiple classes and resource files, makes calls to OpenGL, uses a 3rd party library (jar file) to load meshes and also uses Google Cardboard, so I am unsure how to start to make a Minimal example. The issue is not the code, it is something with project settings or IDE settings.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, I captured a log file, see my edited question.

Comment: Please check if the issue persists in [2017.1 EAP](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/).